Book series about a guy who is saved from an assassin by a crew, taken to their lair and taught magic, before being sent back in time
Looking for a series of books featuring sci-fi, time-travel and magic that I read around 10 years ago.
Plot points I remember:

Book opens up with the MC having a family and living in a well-guarded Residential Neighborhood
-The action jumps to a large assassin that is able to use magic, attempting to assassinate the MC
MC gets saved by a crew that is run by a version of himself that can use magic
MC gets sent back in time to ensure the timeline is safe, getting a warning from his other self that the time to avenge his family will come, as he will come to blows with the ones who sent the assassin. He also learns magic, something that has to do with life force.
In the past, while settling in different locations, he meets a group of people, out of which one is the person that will create the organization that sent the assassin after him, and he will also find the assassin (as a child). He teaches both the assassin and the arch-nemesis in the ways of that magic.
-He uses knowledge from the future to develop the society, at some point building a wheel to leverage the river to help them with different tasks

The book is strongly tied to another book series (sequel to the first series) where:

In the future, nanomachines are released by that same evil organization (HQ on the moon) on the surface of the Earth and devour everything like a virus.
One of the main characters is actually a robot that looks like the guy from the first book, grabs a spaceship and goes to the moon, and the organization leader freaks out because he sees his arch-nemesis. The torch then gets passed to another MC.


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art?  Do you remember the names of any characters or locations in the setting?

I think I remmber the main character being William, and in the nanomachine series there was a Captain Anderson, but that’s all I recall. And the group’s boss that sent the assassin is one of the people the MC teaches magic and starts a secret organization and is bound to be his arch-nemesis.

If it’s any help, those books were downloaded from Google Play, in around 2012, I think.

Remembered something else - a scene in the book, where they leveraged the river to build a contraption to help with carrying heavy loads, build farms. Also, the magic they used involved life force of the trees, nature.

Hi.  Welcome to SF&F.  It is great that you are adding details as you remember them.  The best thing to do would be to edit the additional information into your answer rather than putting it in the comments.  Comments are not necessarily permanent, and editing in new information brings more attention to the question and people are more likely to notice the changes -- and possibly think of an answer.

These two books are "strongly tied" - does that mean they're part of an actual series or one is a prequel/sequel to the other, or are they totally unrelated but just happen to have similar themes?

They are strongly tied - each is part of a series, and the series have a prequel - sequel relation to each other
